# C# Manipulating a button created from an array

Tags: c#

I have crated the below code to create buttons which will display values from an array. I am struggling to figure out how i can manipulate these created buttons later in a different method (test code below shown)

The aim is for the user to click a button which will then disable (which i have functioning) but i also want the button that contains the value of the selected button to be invisible (the part im struggling with)

Error message im receiving is - 'The name 'Value5' does not exist in the current context.' 
I'm thinking i need to pass this array from the Initialize values method to the AssignValues method, but if i do this, i need to pass it through other methods including the buttonclick event handler which includes a bit of code 'BoxesArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(BtnClick);' but i am lost.

```
// CREATE BUTTONS CODE
private void InitializeValues()
    {
        int xPos = 6;
        int lowYPos = 19;
        int highYPos = 19;
        System.Windows.Forms.Button[] ValueArray = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[18];
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            ValueArray[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ValueArray[i].Name = "Value" + (i + 1);
            ValueArray[i].Tag = i + 1; // Tag of button 
            ValueArray[i].Size = new Size(145, 55);
            ValueArray[i].Enabled = false;
            ValueArray[i].FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            ValueArray[i].Text = "£"+Values[i].ToString();
            ValueArray[i].Left = xPos;
            ValueArray[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            ValueArray[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

            if (i <= 8)
            {
                ValueArray[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
                LowNoGroup.Controls.Add(ValueArray[i]);
                ValueArray[i].Top = lowYPos;
                lowYPos = lowYPos + 60;
            }
            if (i > 8)
            {
                ValueArray[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
                HighNoGroup.Controls.Add(ValueArray[i]);
                ValueArray[i].Top = highYPos;
                highYPos = highYPos + 60;
            }

        }
    }
```

.

```
// TEST CODE
private void AssignValues(Button BtnClicked)
    {

       Value5.Visible = false;

    }
```

Here is the full code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int[] Values = new int[18] { 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30, 50, 80, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 30000, 50000, 80000, 125000, 250000 };
    int[] Box = new int[19];
    int howmany = 3;
    int OfferValue = 0;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeValues();
        InitializeBoxes();
    }

    private void InitializeValues()
    {
        int xPos = 6;
        int lowYPos = 19;
        int highYPos = 19;
        System.Windows.Forms.Button[] ValueArray = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[18];
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            ValueArray[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ValueArray[i].Name = "Value" + (i + 1);
            ValueArray[i].Tag = i + 1; // Tag of button 
            ValueArray[i].Size = new Size(145, 55);
            ValueArray[i].Enabled = false;
            ValueArray[i].FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            ValueArray[i].Text = "£"+Values[i].ToString();
            ValueArray[i].Left = xPos;
            ValueArray[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            ValueArray[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

            if (i <= 8)
            {
                ValueArray[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
                LowNoGroup.Controls.Add(ValueArray[i]);
                ValueArray[i].Top = lowYPos;
                lowYPos = lowYPos + 60;
            }
            if (i > 8)
            {
                ValueArray[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
                HighNoGroup.Controls.Add(ValueArray[i]);
                ValueArray[i].Top = highYPos;
                highYPos = highYPos + 60;
            }

        }

    }
    private void InitializeBoxes()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Button[] BoxesArray = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[18];
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            BoxesArray[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            BoxesArray[i].Name = "Box" + (i + 1);
            BoxesArray[i].Tag = i + 1; // Tag of button 
            BoxesArray[i].Size = new Size(350, 350);
            BoxesArray[i].FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            BoxesArray[i].Text = "Box "+ (i+1);
            BoxesArray[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            BoxesArray[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            BoxesArray[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
            BoxLayout.Controls.Add(BoxesArray[i]);

            BoxesArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(BtnClick);
        }
    }

    private void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button BtnClicked = (Button)sender;
        BtnClicked.Enabled = false;

        BtnClicked.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        if (UserBox.Text == "Please choose a box!")
        {
            UserBoxSelection(BtnClicked);
        }
        else
        {
            ChooseBox(BtnClicked);//, OfferValue);
        }

    }

    private void UserBoxSelection(Button BtnClicked)
    {
       // btnClicked.Visible = false; // Hides chosen box from active selection
        UserBox.Text = "You have chosen " + BtnClicked.Text; // Shows your chosen box.
        UserBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(128))))); // Color application
        DealerOffer.Text = "Please choose 3 more boxes!";
    }
    private void ChooseBox(Button BtnClicked)
    {
        howmany--; // subtract 1 from remaining attempts before offer
     // totalboxes--; // subtract 1 from total boxes left
       AssignValues(BtnClicked); 

        BtnClicked.Enabled = false; // Hide selected button
        DealerOffer.Text = ("Please choose " + howmany + " more boxes"); // Display how many more boxes to choose before dealer offer

        if (howmany == 0) // offer a deal
        {
            howmany = 3; // reset tries before offer
            DealerOffer.Text = ("Please choose " + howmany + " more boxes");
            //  Offer(OfferValue); // Run offervalue method
            MessageBox.Show("You have recieved a new offer!");
            BoxLayout.Enabled = false;
            NoDealBtn.Enabled = true;
            DealBtn.Enabled = true;
            DealBtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            NoDealBtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            DealerOffer.Text = ("Your offer is £" + OfferValue + ". Please select Deal or No Deal!");
        }
    }
    private void AssignValues(Button BtnClicked)
    {

        Value5.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: to check functionality, why dont you move your valuesarray deceleration to the form level for now and access it in the 'AssignValues' function.

Comment: i don't quite understand what you are trying to do with your buttons, but just from a standpoint of accessing them, how about you just declare your buttons array as a field of your class, and not as a local variable in your function?

Comment: `this.Controls["Value5"].Visible = false;`

Comment: this.Controls["Value5"].Visible = false;

This seemed to work, but when ran it gives the error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DealOrNoDeal.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `LowNoGroup.Controls["Value5"].Visible = false;`

Comment: This works! Thank you for your help! It is easy to change so that it would be a variable? (Value[i]) so i don't need to write the same piece of code through values 1 to 18?